Inductive Effects of Carboxylic Acids and Carboxylate Anions
I've been studying the inductive effects in carboxylic acids and carboxylate anions. I understand that carboxylic acids ($\ce{R-COOH}$) show a negative inductive effect (–I) due to the electron-withdrawing nature of the oxygen atoms. However, a textbook module I studied mentions that the carboxylate anion ($\ce{R-COO-}$) shows a positive inductive effect (+I). This seems contradictory, as I initially thought both should withdraw electron density. Could you clarify why the carboxylate anion is considered to have a +I effect in some cases?


Could anyone help me understand why my question was downvoted? I'd like to improve it.

For starters https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3709/are-you-confused-by-confusing-question-titles-including-the-word-confusion and more importantly you should write down whatever is in the textbook, certainly not put links to pirate copies of books.

RCOOH has -I due to electron withdrawing nature of O atom.
In RCOO-, there is already a negative charge on O and hence it loses its electron withdrawing nature and acts like a electron donating group in order to disperse the negative charge and attain stability. Hence acts as +I.
